# I have written 2 separate pieces of code which display database records in different ways. How to switch between the ways

Tags: javascript, php, laravel

The code below displays the same images in a different ways, I want to create a button which switches between the 2 ways. My first thought is to create a button which leads to `www.domain.com/second-view` route which will display view that will contain the second code piece but that doesn't sound too smooth to me for some reason. The other thought is to create a toggle button which will hide the current view, and display the other view and vice versa. I'm just looking for a few tips and opinions on how should I do that.

```
@foreach($images as $image)
        <div class='imageContainer'>
            <div class="stickyContainer blackGradient">
                <h1 class='imageTitle'>{{$image->name}}</h1>
                <img class='uploadedImg' src='{{url("storage/uploads/images/".$image->file_name)}}' alt='Random image'/>
                <a class='specialA' href='{{url("image/".$image->id)}}'></a>
                @auth
                <div class='votingContainer'>
                    <a href='#' class='vote {{ ( auth()->user()->votes()->whereImageId($image->id)->first() && auth()->user()->votes()->whereImageId($image->id)->first()->vote == 1 ) ? "liked" : "like" }}' id='{{$image->id}}'></a>
                    <a href='#' class='vote {{ ( auth()->user()->votes()->whereImageId($image->id)->first() && auth()->user()->votes()->whereImageId($image->id)->first()->vote == 0 ) ? "disliked" : "dislike" }}' id='{{$image->id}}'></a>
                </div>
            @endauth
            </div>
        </div>
    @endforeach

<div class="grid">
    @foreach($images as $image)
    <div class="grid-item">
        <img src="{{url(" storage/uploads/images/ ".$image->file_name)}}" />
        <a class='specialA' href='{{url("image/".$image->id)}}'></a>
    </div>
    @endforeach
</div>
```

Comment: Hiding one and showing the other is exactly the way I would approach this if it's something you want them to be able to change back and forth however much they want. If you have a div with a unique id containing each set of images, it's pretty easy to do something like document.getElementById('grid-box').style.display = none; to hide a box, or display = block/inline/whatever; to show

Comment: And I would agree that loading a new view whenever they switch would be inelegant if you expect frequent swapping. If you expect that a user will most likely stick with one view and not change, then using a separate view would free your server the work of looping through everything a second time.

Comment: Render the 2 ways in 2 separate divs then bind jquery to hide/show upon button click.